# How to do active class add/remove click the thumbnail?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. There, showing images. But it is not showing big image respectively by click on the small image.

Here is the jQuery code:

```js
$('.preview-thumbnail li a').click(function () {       
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        if(target){
            $(target).toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="preview">
            <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
                @{ int i = 0;
                    foreach (var item in Model.Images)
                    {
                        i++;
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-@i"><img style="width:400px;height:252px" src="@item.ImagePath"></div>
 
                    }
                }
            </div>
            <ul class="preview-thumbnail nav nav-tabs">
                @{ int j = 0;
                    foreach (var item in Model.Images)
                    {
                        j++;
                        <li class="active"><a data-target="#pic-@j" data-toggle="tab"><img style="width:200px;height:50px" src="@item.ImagePath"></a></li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I show an image popup respectively onclick of the thumbnail? Please help me...

Comment: why won't you use the https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ ?

Comment: Are you missing jQuery in your project or just forgot to add it to the snippet you added here?

Comment: @Edwin : I have used `$(this).addClass("active");` but now now all `<div class="tab-pane active"` class are `active`. how can I remove active from previous one after click on another small image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to toggle classes, you can use JQuery's `.toggleClass('active')`, like this:

```
 $('.preview-thumbnail li a').click(function () {       
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        if(target){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        }
 });
```

It will remove active class if the element already have that class.

Do you want that when the user clicks on the thumbnail, to make it bigger? There are JQuery plugins to help making this effect, like [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) , since you are using JQuery already.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.preview-thumbnail li a').click(function () {       
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        if(target){
            $(target).addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

for remove class you can use

```
$(target).removeClass('active');
```

Comment: now all `<div class="tab-pane active"` class are `active`

Comment: how can I remove `active` class when click on another small image ?

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
    $('.preview-thumbnail li a').click(function () {       
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        if(target){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
   });
```

If it is not showing big. You open inspect browser check class active.